# How can I stream radio in my iOS app? Swift and AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am currently using AVFoundation. The problem is that if I find a .m3u the stream works but I can not find the .m3u for any radio station. I am trying to get this one to work. http://player.listenlive.co/35821

Here is my code

```
   @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
 var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://player.listenlive.co/35821/en"))

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggle()
}

func toggle() {
    if playButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
        playRadio()
    } else {
        pauseRadio()
    }
}

func playRadio() {
    player.play()
    playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

func pauseRadio() {
    player.pause()
    playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is wrong. You need to have the direct URL to the m3u8 file. Many m3u8s can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing